# Installing QGIS plugins offline?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, installation, offline

"Due to various IT policies at my workplace, QGIS is installed on a machine (Window 7, 64bits and QGIS 2.6) that is not connected to the internet. I wish to install a couple of QGIS plugins on this system.

I have downloaded the required plugins and save them on usb key. How do I install them in QGIS?"

i 've already tried :
-Unzip in folder \qgis\python\plugin
=>says in plugin manager "plugins broken" displayed in red

As i'm a new user, I'll be very glad to read a step by step how to do that.
I am seeking to get archeoCAD,numericalDigitize and numericalVertexEdit working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two places where python plugins can be found:

1. in the applications path (`C:\OSGEO4W\apps\qgis\python\plugins` or `C:\Programs\QGIS Brighton\apps\qgis\python\plugins`)
2. In you user directory `C:\users\username\.qgis2\python\plugins`

The first place is only for core plugins like fTools and GdalTools, while the contributed go into the second one. The folder `.qgis2` might be hidden by the operating system. Make sure you preserve the folder order. The plugin has to be in a folder with its name, and in that folder there has to be an `__init__.py` and `metadata.txt` files. It might be that your zip programme creates another subfolder, which can not be used by the plugin manager.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it's moving the right way. But i'm still getting some issues. What i've done: unzip and take care of the subfolder creation and place the content in : C:\users\username\.qgis2\python\plugins Plugins appears in QGIS plugin manger. but are red marked, with warning messages such as:"this plugin is broken, no module named nameofmodule" or "invalid syntax". I do have __ init__.py and metadata.txt files in the folder with the plugin's name(i think)

Comment: Can you try installing those plugins on another computer (e.g. at home), and copy/replace the whole .qgis2 folder? A Windows user name with non-ASCII-characters may also spoil the plugins.

Comment: Thanks, I needed a reboot, it's all clear except one plugin but i guess it is really broken or not compatible !!

Comment: Which plugin remains broken for you?

Comment: All three plugins now works fine :) i downloaded a fourth to implement mgrs crs and this one remains broken. But i can manage without! If you dont have a solution i still thanks you a lot for the previous answers :)

Comment: Where can I find that plugin?

Comment: I found it there: https://github.com/volaya/mgrs-tools

Comment: The plugin is broken for me too, but it is not in the official repository anyway: https://github.com/volaya/mgrs-tools/issues/1.

Comment: I've read some tips, that it could come from the dash of the "ext-libs" folder in the mgrstools folder. I know little about python. I'll continue my research

Comment: For folks who are dealing with the "broken plugin" problem: ensure that when you unzip the plugin, that the folder chain looks like this: `python/plugins/NAME_OF_PLUGIN/All plugin files here`. My issue was that when I unzipped the plugin the unzipping process created a folder within a folder, so it looked like `python/plugins/NAME_OF_PLUGIN/NAME_OF_PLUGIN/all files here`.