# Could not find Easy custom labeling tool in plugin manager

Tags: qgis, windows

I could not find the tool "Easy custom labeling" in Plugin Manager.

My colleague can install the tool for QGIS in her PC but she uses Windows 7 while I use windows 10. Could anyone advise me how to get that tool installed for windows 10?

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the EasyCustomLabeling tool is not listed in the plugin manager currently - this has been an issue for several people, as seen in this github thread: https://github.com/haubourg/EasyCustomLabeling/issues/20

To use the plugin, you can download the plugin at the official QGIS plugin repository: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/EasyCustomLabeling/

And then install it following the directions listed in this answer:
[How to Install QGIS 2.6 plugins offline](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127785/how-to-install-qgis-2-6-plugins-offline)